# JSON File has É in it. When I download from feed on server data returned can't be parsed. Same data in local copy in projects works downloadis?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, download, feed

When downloading data from server `JSON` feed, I can't parse the data received as the data has this É . I am running in swift4. I create a copy the data file into my project locally and the parsing works, using  `JSONDecoder().decode` with the data structure no problem.
I believe it has something to do with how I create my request object or session config but I am not too versed in this area.
I think its from `charset=ISO-8859-1`
don't know how to use this in my request/session to handle this character
spent a lot of time on this not sure where to look

Comment: did you try utf8 encoding?

Comment: I use this method dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

Comment: I tested using encoding I'm new to this so I don't know how to answer. properly. I was able to read each byte and when I get to the area where the É the code would crash                                  let truncatedServerAns = data[c..<readBytes]
                 let tsaData = Data(bytes: truncatedServerAns) newString += String(data: tsaData, encoding: .utf8)!
                 print("newString : *****\(newString)***** ", newString)
                 c += 1
                 readBytes += 1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.
All I needed to do was convert the data from charset=ISO-8859-1 to utf8

I created a NSString out of the data returned from the response.

let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:

String.EncodingConversionOptions.allowLossy.rawValue)

let s = responseString! as String

let d = Data(s.utf8)

then I was able to pass the converted Data object into the JSONDescoder()

now I am new to programming so if there is a better way I could have done this I would like feedback because String.EncodingConversionOptions.allowLossy.rawValue was just through trial and error.

thank you
Peter